# Go Lang: Can't change children's stdin

Tags: linux, go, stdin

I want to completelly drop **STDIN** in parent and children processes.

**CONTEXT:**
I am spawning children process from main Go process. It is spawned in Go routine. Somehow FDs (stdin in this case) are inherited by children process. My goal is to set stdin of children process to nil, in order to forbid any stdin to the children process.

I tried:

```
os.Stdin = nil

os.Stdin = os.NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/null")
```

Only "solution" which I found is dirty:

```
func init() {
    go func() {
        for {
            io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
        }
    }()
}
```

Does anybody know better solution?

**UPDATE:**
**os.Stdin = nil** won't work if Go program is reading from /dev/tty

I am spawning [FFUF](https://vscode.dev/github/ffuf/ffuf/blob/5c489aea78b9a76472ca3f0b09774078932c9d59/pkg/interactive/termhandler.go?fbclid=IwAR2OTKYnC27a-6CkGocduA8bbzGy9X0bCXxGD3-97JLuHR-5ne9n5xz_PyA#L18-L31)

```
go func() {
    tty, err := os.Open("/dev/tty")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer tty.Close()

    inreader := bufio.NewScanner(tty)
    inreader.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    started <- true
    for inreader.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf("handle: " + inreader.Text())
    }
}()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249561/discussion-on-question-by-dusan-panic-go-lang-cant-change-childrens-stdin).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You need to spawn a process without TTY.
To do it, it is necessary to perform syscall **SysProcAttr** with **Setsid** and **Setctty** parameters.

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo")

cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Setsid:  true,
    Setctty: false,
}

cmd.Start()

cmd.Write([]byte("hello grep\ngoodbye grep"))
cmd.Close()

cmd.Wait()
```

Comment: TBH, I still don't "get" it: the processes which need a real TTY won't usually work when you disconnect them from one. And if they are run via `exec.Cmd` with `Stdin` set to `nil`, they will have their stdin FD opened to `/dev/null`, and will hence not "see" the TTY. So, to require something as strange as you've proposed here, a process should be doing something weird like trying to open its stdin from some non-standard place—maybe using Linux's special files, I dunno.

Comment: @kostix as I understand (from [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html)) STDIN is attached to certain TTY. So setting STDIN to nil won't change reading from TTY. That is how I understand how this worked.

Comment: You mean the processes you have spawned explicitly opened the TTY, like with opening the "/dev/tty" Linux-specfic pseudo file?

Comment: Yes, that is what I saw in [code](https://github.dev/ffuf/ffuf/blob/5c489aea78b9a76472ca3f0b09774078932c9d59/pkg/interactive/posix.go#L7-L9)

Comment: I see. Well, the word "interactive" in the pathname there is a hint ;-) By the way, the author of that code is not correct: POSIX does not define `/dev/tty`; it's a pure Linux-ism. Also a well-behaving Unix program won't try to open `/dev/tty` directly—basically for the reasons led to this your very question. Instead, it should have tested whether its stdin's FD is opened to a terminal device (which is, by the way, is not portable as it's defined by POSIX on the level of `libc` or supporting libraries).